# Can i call a specific function inside `useEffect` in React?

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

I have a canvas component in react. I am using `useEffect` to get the canvas element. So i have defined all needed functions in `useEffect`, as you can see below

```js
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react"
import * as blobs2Animate from "blobs/v2/animate"

export const CornerExpand = () => {
  const canvasRef = useRef<HTMLCanvasElement>(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    const canvas = canvasRef.current!
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")
    const animation = blobs2Animate.canvasPath()

    const width = canvas.clientWidth * window.devicePixelRatio
    const height = canvas.clientHeight * window.devicePixelRatio
    canvas.width = width
    canvas.height = height

    const renderAnimation = () => {
      if (!ctx) return
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height)
      ctx.fillStyle = "#E0F2FE"
      ctx.fill(animation.renderFrame())
      requestAnimationFrame(renderAnimation)
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(renderAnimation)

    const size = Math.min(width, height) * 1
    const defaultOptions = () => ({
      blobOptions: {
        seed: Math.random(),
        extraPoints: 36,
        randomness: 0.7,
        size,
      },
      canvasOptions: {
        offsetX: -size / 2.2,
        offsetY: -size / 2.2,
      },
    })

    const loopAnimation = () => {
      animation.transition({
        duration: 4000,
        timingFunction: "ease",
        callback: loopAnimation,
        ...defaultOptions(),
      })
    }

    animation.transition({
      duration: 0,
      callback: loopAnimation,
      ...defaultOptions(),
    })

    const fullscreen = () => {
      const options = defaultOptions()
      options.blobOptions.size = Math.max(width, height) * 1.6
      options.blobOptions.randomness = 1.4
      options.canvasOptions.offsetX = -size / 2
      options.canvasOptions.offsetY = -size / 2
      animation.transition({
        duration: 2000,
        timingFunction: "elasticEnd0",
        ...options,
      })
    }
  }, [canvasRef])

  return (
    <div>
      <canvas className="absolute top-0 left-0 h-full w-full" ref={canvasRef} />
    </div>
  )
}
export default CornerExpand
```

Everything works as well, but now I have a problem. I want to execute the `fullscreen()` function when a button is clicked in the parent component. Since I have defined the function in `useEffect`, I can't call it directly, isn't it? What can I do to solve this?

Comment: you can move the full screen function outside of the useEffect

Comment: that way you can call it inside the useEffect as well as on click

Comment: @RobertTerrell thanks for your answer, but the fullscreen function need access to the `animation`, `options` etc. variables, which are defined in useEffect. I only want to execute the function in a onClick Event listener

Comment: You can pass those variables into the function as parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this.

```
export const CornerExpand = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
//....
  {
  //...
    const fullscreen = () => {
      const options = defaultOptions()
      options.blobOptions.size = Math.max(width, height) * 1.6
      options.blobOptions.randomness = 1.4
      options.canvasOptions.offsetX = -size / 2
      options.canvasOptions.offsetY = -size / 2
      animation.transition({
        duration: 2000,
        timingFunction: "elasticEnd0",
        ...options,
      })
    }
    ref.current = fullscreen;
  }, [canvasRef]);
```

You can wrap this comp with `React.forwardRef`. And call it from parent.

```
<CornerExpand ref={fullscreenCallbackRef} />
```

And then call like this

```
fullscreenCallbackRef.current()
```

Comment: thank you and how can i call this function from parent component?

Comment: You can use forwardRef to pass Ref from parent to child